# management users with Zend_Auth and Zend_Session

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-session

I want to Zend_Auth and Zend_Session to save user sessions and logins information

whats the easy and best way for implements following items:

```
1-Disallow multiple concurrent logins for the specific user

2-List all of all user currently logged in 

3-Admin could logout of specific user or destroy specific session
```

Is there any special ZF or PHP API or library that can do the above?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use [Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Session/SaveHandler/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable.html) or create your custom session SaveHandler implementing [Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Session/SaveHandler/Zend_Session_SaveHandler_Interface.html).

You may activate it in `application.ini`:

```
resources.session.saveHandler.class = "Zend_Session_SaveHandler_DbTable"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.name = "session"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary.session_id = "session_id"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary.save_path = "save_path"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primary.name = "name"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment.sessionId = "sessionId"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment.sessionSavePath = "sessionSavePath"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.primaryAssignment.sessionName = "sessionName"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.modifiedColumn = "modified"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.dataColumn = "session_data"
resources.session.saveHandler.options.lifetimeColumn = "lifetime"
```

See [Session Application resource docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) for more info.